# Comparing convex functions near infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ is a strictly convex and incresing function. Let $p>1$ be a real number and assume that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t^p}=0\tag{1}$$

Can I conclude that there is a positive $1\le q<p$ such that if $t$ is big enough then $$f(t)\le t^q \tag{2}$$

I was trying to prove $(2)$ by contradiction. If my calculations are right, I managed to prove that if $(2)$ is not true, then

$$t^p\ge f(t)\ge t^{q_n},\ \forall \ t\ge t_n,\ t_n\to\infty,\ q_n\to p \tag{3},$$

however, I can't see any contradiction with $(3)$. Maybe a counter example?

Comment: The answer is well-known to people working in calculus of variations: the precise growth condition (2) is not equivalent to the limit (1).

Comment: I was expecting this type of comment. Thank you @Siminore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(t)=\frac{t^p}{\ln t}.
$$
Then
$$
f'(t)=\frac{t^{p-1}(p\ln t-1)}{(\ln t)^2},\quad
f''(t)=\frac{t^{p-2}(2+(1-2\,p)\ln t+p\,(p-1)\,(\ln t)^2)}{(\ln t)^3}.
$$
For $t$ large enough $f'>0$ and $f''>0$, so that $f$ is strictly increasing and strictly convex on an interval $[\,T_p,\infty)$. Also
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t^p}=0,
$$
but if $q<p$ then
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t^q}=\infty.
$$